# get only facebook profile picture using embed code

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, phonegap-facebook-plugin

I am trying to get only facebook profile picture using embed code but page name and like button display in the preview.

```
<div class="fb-page" 
data-tabs=""
data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook"
data-width="10" 

data-hide-cover="true"
data-show-facepile="false"

data-small-header="true">
```

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to put the button in a div with a fixed width and overflow hidden, but ultimately this widget is **not** intended for this use.

There is an API endpoint intended for this use, though - [`/[user/page ID]/picture`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/picture/).

So, you can simply do `<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/page-id/picture">`.

For example: https://graph.facebook.com/facebook/picture

Comment: It's work I apply it like this.`   <div class="fb-profilephoto" 
data-tabs="" data-href="https://graph.facebook.com/{{ $user->SchoolFBProfile}}/picture"
data-width="100" 
data-hide-cover="true"
data-show-facepile="false"
 data-small-header="true">
 </div>`